# Windows Command Line: execute a .bat file in a new console window

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-console

I have 4 DOS batch files:

```
GoCore1.bat
GoCore2.bat
GoCore3.bat
GoCore4.bat
```

I would like to launch each bat file in its own console window *from* a single .bat file (go.bat).  Windows 7 is the OS.

Is this possible?  If so, what is the syntax to create a new console window and start executing GoCoreX.bat?

Any constructive feedback to sharpen the question is appreciated: please do not down vote without leaving constructive feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [START command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) in your `go.bat`:

```
start "myWindow1" GoCore1.bat
start "myWindow2" GoCore2.bat
start "myWindow3" GoCore3.bat
start "myWindow4" GoCore4.bat
```

START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]

```
Key:
   title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
   path        Starting directory.
   command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
   parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
```